# Where should submit buttons be located for a form located in a Bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, forms, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Below is example HTML straight from [the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#varying-modal-content) except that I added an `id` to the form element.  Why are they showing the buttons outside of the form? Shouldn't they be located within the form so that when clicked, the form is submitted?  Please see my typical JavaScript at the bottom.  If not, is it required to attach an event to the `button.btn-primary` which will then submit the form, or not even use this event and just do the work within the click primary button event?

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New message</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form id="my-form">
          <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Recipient:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
          </div>
          <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Message:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text"></textarea>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send message</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My typical JS would be something like the following:

```
const form = document.getElementById( "my-form" );
form.addEventListener( "submit", function ( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Make a XMLHttpRequest as necessary
} );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `button` element has an optional [`form` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) that is used to associate it with a `form`. This allows the `button` to be positioned anywhere, not necessarily inside of the `form` element. It also allows for multiple `button` elements to be associated with a single `form` in cases where different submit parameters might be needed.

Comment: Thanks Scott.  Doing this way seems much more appropriate.  My button now looks like `<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" form="my-form">Save Project</button>`, but it is not triggering the submit event of the form.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Nevermind.  When testing, the form was empty :)  Thanks again!  EDIT Actually, maybe not out of the woods yet...

Comment: @user1032531 Make sure to use the `id` of the `form` in the `form` attribute.

Comment: Thanks again Scott.  I had already been doing so.  Changed the button HTML from `type="button"` to `type="submit"` and think all is good.